# Asp.net MVC post form null value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am currently following Mosh's asp.net mvc course.

Recently I got to using form to post data, but I encountered a problem that I cannot solve.

So the form for adding a Customer uses `NewCustomerViewModel` that contains available `MembershipTypes`. Then, in the form I use a drop down list to select one and bind it with this Customer.

However, after the submit, the `MembershipType` in Customer is set to `null` although `MembershipTypeID` is bound properly.

I have no idea how to solve this problem. Any advice is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

**The code:**

Customer class:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(70)]
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSubscribedToNewsletter { get; set; }
    public MembershipType MemebershipType { get; set; }
    public int MembershipTypeID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Birthdate { get; set; }
}
```

Customer controller:

```
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDBContext context;

    public CustomerController(ApplicationDBContext ctxt)
    {
        this.context = ctxt;
    }

    public CustomerController()
    {
        this.context = new ApplicationDBContext();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        context.Dispose();
    }
    // GET: Customer
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var model = context.Customers.Include(x => x.MemebershipType).ToList();
        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        var ct = context.Customers.Include(c => c.MemebershipType).SingleOrDefault(c => c.ID == id);
        if (ct == null) return HttpNotFound();
        return View(ct);
    }

    public ActionResult New()
    {
        var membershiptypes = context.MembershipTypes.ToList();
        var viewmodel = new NewCustomerViewModel
        {
            MembershipTypes = membershiptypes
        };
        return View(viewmodel);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Customer customer)
    {
        context.Customers.Add(customer);
        context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Customer");
    }
}
```

NewCustomerViewModel

```
public class NewCustomerViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<MembershipType> MembershipTypes { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

View for adding a new customer:

```
    @model Vidly.ViewModels.NewCustomerViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "New";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>New Customer</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Customer"))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(c => c.Customer.Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Customer.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Date of birth</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Customer.Birthdate, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(c => c.Customer.IsSubscribedToNewsletter) Subscribed to newsletter?
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Membership type</label>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.Customer.MembershipTypeID,
       new SelectList(Model.MembershipTypes, "ID", "Name"), "Select membership type", new {@class="form-control"})
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        Save
    </button>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal since you did not set the `MembershipType`, you set the `MembershipTypeId`

and when it is saved in the database the `MembershipTypeId` is Saved

Then when you query this customer via the Details Action you will get the `MembershipType` populated properly.

Alternatively you can Populate it using the `contextManager`

By simply

```
customer.MembershipType = context.MembershipTypes.SingleOrDefault(m => m.id == customer.MembershipTypeId);
```

but this will cost you unnecessary round to the database.

Comment: Thanks @J. Scott for the editing...Looks much better Now

Comment: so what should i do? i changed `@Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.Customer.MemebershipTypeID,` to `@Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.Customer.MemebershipType,` and i still got the same problem

Comment: @Jania Change the code back to 
<pre>
c => c.Customer.MembershipTypeId
<code>
And everything will work and its ok for the `MembershipType` to be `null`

Comment: and in the `Action`
add repopulate the `MembershipType` using its `Id`

Comment: thank you, i finally understood and it started working properly